# Notification API: instanciating a notification Microsoft Edge causes a DOMException unknow error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, notifications, runtime-error

I am using Notification API. It has to be compatible with Microsoft Edge.
It causes an error:

```
pushNotification(title, opts, force = false) {
    if (this.areNotificationsOn() && (force || !window.document.hasFocus())) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION - START");
        const notification = new Notification(title, opts);
        console.log("NOTIFICATION - END");

        const timer = this.$timeout(() => {
            notification.close();
        }, _.get(this.businessConfig, "notifications.timeout", 15000));

        notification.onclick = () => {
            this.$timeout.cancel(timer);
            window.focus();
            notification.close();
        };

        return notification;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The first `console.log("NOTIFICATION - START");` showed up, but not the second one.

Did somebody experience that already?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: You might want an image to illustrate my problem, so here it is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So this error was due to `opts` passed to Notification constructor.

It contains a body with a text and an image. I pass an image in the base64 format because I was using require. I was not able to give it a base64. Edge doesn't support it (chrome does).

Hope it will help someone!